# Openshift Multiple Domains Apps

Tags: openshift, multiple-domains, openshift-client-tools

On Openshift, I have 2 diferent apps on 2 diferent domains whose I administer.

If i run :

```
rhc apps
```

it shows both apps correctly.

But if i try to assign an alias to any of the apps (or basically issue any command to any of the apps),it always says:

```
Application 'app1' not found
```

For the record, I already ran "rhc setup" and cloned the git repo of both apps locally.

There is some limitation on running multiple domains apps? If not, then what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to specify the --namespace option with the name of the domain that the application is in, if it is not in your primary domain.

```
rhc alias-add <application> <alias> [--namespace NAME]
```